# How to specify a VCS dependency with both an HTTPS and an SSH URL

Tags: pipenv

I am writing a Python application. It requires a certain version of Python, and some third party dependencies that are available on PyPI. It also depends on a private Python library that I have in a private Git repository. I'd like to depend on a specific Git tag. I need to be able to spin up this environment both on a local machine (where I have SSH access to the git repository) and on a CI server (where I have HTTPS access to the git repository using a username and password). I'm struggling to set up my Pipfile in a way that will work for both cases.

I tried to specify the URL dependency with the SSH URL and then on the CI machine where I only have HTTPS access, tried to first install the library via https directly into the virtual environment. The trouble is that the entire URL (including the protocol) is stored in the Pipfile.lock (and the entire URL is checked by pip when comparing the existing installation to the new one).

pipenv install the dependency from ssh:

```
$ pipenv install -e  git+ssh://git@git.domain.com/my-private-lib@v0.1#egg=my-private-lib
```

of course if I try to just sync on the CI machine, it will fail:

```
$ git clone my-project
$ cd my-project
$ pipenv sync
# Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved.
```

trying to install using https before running pipenv:

```
$ git clone my-project
$ cd my-project
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install my-private-repo @ git+https://my_user:my_token@git.domain.com/my-private-lib@v0.1
$ deactivate
$ pipenv sync
```

But this still will tell me that it can't reach ssh://git@git.domain...

I appreciate that the point of pipenv is to specify concrete dependencies with concrete sources. In my case, the source is slightly different between two machines. Is there any way around this? Perhaps a way to turn off exact URL checking and just check the git hash?